# Center a UL horizontally within a DIV

Tags: css

I'm currently trying to center a `<ul>` horizontally within a `<div>` and it's not for budging, I've tried `margin: 0 auto;` and `text-align: center;` and neither seem to work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pU2Gx/)

**HTML**

```
<!-- START RECENT WORK -->
<div id="recentwork">
  <div class="display">
    <h2>Recent Work</h2>
    <ul>
      <li class="recent"><img src="http://www.gezzamondo.co.uk/images/apps/ticketsoup/ticketsoup-01.jpg" /></li>
      <li class="recent"><img src="http://www.gezzamondo.co.uk/images/apps/ticketsoup/ticketsoup-01.jpg" /></li>
      <li class="recent last"><img src="http://www.gezzamondo.co.uk/images/apps/ticketsoup/ticketsoup-01.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- CLOSE RECENT WORK -->
```

**CSS**

```
#recentwork {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ececec;
    clear: both;
    padding: 80px 0;
}

#recentwork .display {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#recentwork .display ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#recentwork .display ul li.recent {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 200px;
}

#recentwork .display ul li.recent.last {
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: Why are you floating the `li.recent` elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets use the old school technique of **centering the list** by giving a `display: inline-block`. Do it this way:

```
#recentwork .display {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

#recentwork .display ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#recentwork .display ul li.recent {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/pU2Gx/3/

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto` will only work if you have a fixed width.

I'm assuming you want the individual list items to still be *left-aligned* within the list itself. In that case, try this:

```
<div class="centerlist">
  <ul>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>List item</li>
    <li>A longer list item than the other two</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.centerlist {
    text-align: center;
}
.centerlist > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#recentwork {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#ececec;
    clear:both;
    padding:80px 0;
}

.display {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.display ul {
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 820px;
}

.recent{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 270px;
}
```

Note the use of `display: inline-block` and the use of proper widths.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6LJE/

Comment: I would do this *way* differently today using flexbox, and no floats.

Answer (score 0):

Your ul needs to have a width for it to be centered.

For example:

```
#recentwork .display ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:700px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pU2Gx/2/)**

Comment: The list should expand to accommodate the items if it is floated or the inside is cleared. Using an explicit width here is wrong.

Comment: @Asad - Where does the question ask for this?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm making the assumption that the OP wants the list to fit its contents, and not have an arbitrary width.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following CSS:

```
#recentwork .display ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#recentwork .display ul li.recent {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 200px;
}
```